# Java protobuf in Scala

Tags: java, scala, protocol-buffers

I need to write an application server in scala which takes Protobufs from HTTP POST payloads and process it.

Is it possible to compile proto files to Java files, compile them into Java bytecode and use it directly from scala. Or do I really need to use a scala Protobuf compiler?

Answer (score 2):

why not?.. just let know scala about your compiled generated java code.